# Convert list of lists of vectors to data frame in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of lists of numeric vectors. I would like to

1. sum each vector
2. make each inner list of scalars into a vector
3. combine the vectors into one data frame where the vectors are rows

I hacked together the following, but it seems that this is very clumsy and not the R way. I suspect that if I use `rapply` and four steps that I am doing something wrong (not in terms of results, but in terms of efficiency and understanding). Is there a right way to do this operation?

```
dat1 <- list(list(1:2, 3:4), list(5:6, 7:8))
dat2 <- rapply(dat1, sum, how="list") 
dat3 <- lapply(dat2, unlist)
dat4 <- do.call(rbind, dat3)
dat5 <- data.frame(dat4)
```

So the desired output is

```
> dat5
  X1 X2
1  3  7
2 11 15
> class(dat5)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if it's any more efficient, but here's something similar:

```
as.data.frame(matrix(rapply(dat1,sum), nrow=length(dat1), byrow=TRUE))
X1 X2
1  3  7
2 11 15
```

Comment: For sure more efficient. You are trading `do.call`, `unlist`, `lapply` and `rbind` whith `matrix`. Not to mention all the copies made by `<-`. Even only `as.data.frame` is faster than `data.frame`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to get you there in one go, without much difference in efficiency from using `matrix`

```
> as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, rapply(dat1, sum, how = "list")))
#   X1 X2
# 1  3  7
# 2 11 15

> f1 <- function() 
      as.data.frame(matrix(rapply(dat1,sum), nrow=length(dat1), byrow=TRUE))
> f2 <- function() 
      as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, rapply(dat1, sum, how = "list")))
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f1(), f2())
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr    min      lq median       uq     max neval
#  f1() 91.047 92.7105  93.94 102.2855 199.305   100
#  f2() 95.213 97.3150  98.43 101.8240 134.403   100
```

Almost a wash for this example.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarking lesson, too. Low mean/high variance vs high mean/low variance. I guess I finally found a reasonable use for `rapply`.

Comment: But each vector in my data frame are still lists. Is there a way to fix this? Or am I back to my original solution?

Comment: Yes (in this case they would be integers).

Comment: It looks like `rapply` with `unlist` then passing through `matrix` solve this. I should mark the other solution since it passes through `unlist` and is better for my case.